# Restful Web Service Repository not routing properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest

I've built a RESTful Web API service using ASP.NET MVC 5, following the instructions in [this article](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-web-api.html). As part of the process, I set up a controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [FromServices]
    public IAccountRepository Repository { get; set; }

    [HttpGet(Name = "GetAll")]
    public IEnumerable<UserAccount> GetAll() {
        return Repository.GetAll();
    }

    [HttpGet("(id)", Name = "GetUserAccount")]
    public IActionResult GetUserAccount(int id) {
        var account = Repository.GetUserAccount(id);
        if (account == null)
            return HttpNotFound();
        return new ObjectResult(account);
    }

    [HttpPost("(item)", Name = "AddUserAccount")]
    public IActionResult Add([FromBody] UserAccount item) {
        if (item == null)
            return HttpBadRequest();
        return CreatedAtRoute("GetUserAccount", new { controller = "Account", id = item.Id }, item);
    }

    [HttpDelete( "(id)", Name = "RemoveUserAccount" )]
    public void Remove(int id) {
        Repository.Remove(id);
    }

    [HttpPost("(id)", Name = "UpdateUserAccount")]
    public IActionResult Update([FromBody] UserAccount item) {
        if (item == null)
            return HttpBadRequest();

        if (!Repository.Update(item))
            return HttpNotFound();

        return new NoContentResult();
    }
}
```

When I access this service from a browser using the URL http://localhost:2733/api/account, the `GetAll action executes, which is OK, but when I try to access it using the URL http://localhost:2733/api/account/getall, I get a 404 error.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: It looks like the default route gets executed. Do you have the call to routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); somwehere in your boostrapping code?

Comment: I can't find that anywhere in the project

Comment: Try adding it before your default route definition. Check out the link: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

Comment: I've read the link but I still don't know where to put the call. My service uses DNX; I can't find a class in the project called  `RouteConfig`. And this is an WEB API service application. I did everything in the original article. I don't understand this

Comment: I tried creating a new class called `RouteConfig` and calling the `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes()` method, but the method isn't defined in the `RouteCollection` class.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by changing the methods in the controller so they matched the signatures in the default Values controller.  The controller class now looks like:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [FromServices]
    public IAccountRepository Repository { get; set; }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<UserAccount> Get() {
        return Repository.GetAll();
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Get(int id) {
        var account = Repository.GetUserAccount(id);
        if (account == null)
            return HttpNotFound();
        return new ObjectResult(account);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody] UserAccount item) {
        if (item == null)
            return HttpBadRequest();
        var account = Repository.Add(item);
        return new ObjectResult(account);
    }

    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public void Delete(int id) {
        Repository.Remove(id);
    }

    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Put(int id, [FromBody] UserAccount item) {
        if (item == null)
            return HttpBadRequest();

        if (!Repository.Update(item))
            return HttpNotFound();

        return new ObjectResult(item);
    }
}
```

The other thing I've learned is that in order to configure MVC routing, the `Startup` class in Startup.cs requires the following line in the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddMvc();
```

It also requires this line in the `Configure` method:

```
app.UseMvc();
```

With these changes, the controller works and routes requests to the proper method.